# Responding to prompts automatically?

Tags: prompt, read

Lets say I have a script called RPS that simulates rock paper scissors.
For example lets say I run the script with "$sh RPS".

The script will echo "paper" and then prompt me for an input. Obviously if I type in "scissors" I will win.

Is there a way to write a script that runs the RPS script, and then enters the prompts for me based on whether the AI used rock, paper, or scissors?

Comment: Yes there is, but two-way communication is not straightforward-- too easy to get stuck. Ask more specifically about the programming language you are interested in.

Comment: Perhaps [expect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect)?

Comment: I'm working in bash, so I want it to look like this:
(script1) (script2)
I can pass on script2 as an argument to script 1.
Script 1 will run script 2 and respond to prompts until script 2 exits. How would I go about coding script1?